# A particular database design question

Tags: sql, database-design, data-representation

My current database consists of the following tables.

Store users ratings of given questions -

```
user( uid(varchar), qid(varchar), rating(varchar), primary key(uid, qid) )
```

Store the question and its id -

```
questions( uid(varchar), question(text), primary key(qid) )
```

Store the relationship that questions have amongst each other -

```
related( qid(varchar), related_qid(varchar), relation(varchar), primary key(qid, related_qid, relation) )
```

Each question is related to at least one other question; for instance, question1 and question2 could be related in that the average rating of question1 is expected to be greater than that of question2. This relationship would be stored in the "related" table as

INSERT INTO related (qid, related_qid, relation) VALUES (1, 2, gt)
where 'gt' means "greater than".

The issue is that encoding the relations doesn't seem at all elegant. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: What is relation(varchar)? Is that the nature of the relationship expressed as a comment? A relation-type? EDIT: OK, I see it's a code or shorthand for a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change the types of the columns. I think `qid` and `related_qid` would be best as integers for fast joins, and `related` could be changed to an enumeration type if one is available in your database (for example MySQL has [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)).

PS: It's also possible to simulate an enumeration in databases that don't have an enum type  by using a table to store the possible values and setting up a foreign key constraint to this table.

I'm also unsure why your user table has a two-column primary key. I would imagine that a single column would be sufficient, but it's hard to be sure without knowing more about your application.

Other than these points it seems a reasonable design.

Comment: In regards to the two-column primary key, my intention is to prevent multiple ratings for the same user and question. For example, after inserting uid=1, qid=1, rating=1 one cannot insert uid=1, qid=1, rating=2. Is that not a good approach?

Comment: @dnbwise: That sounds OK, but then I have to question your choice of table name. Perhaps `user_rating` instead?

Comment: you've made some helpful points. I think the issue that I have is - to me - this implies a potential redundancy in the related table. So, by saying qid=1, related_qid=2, relation=gt, I'm also saying qid=2, related_qid=1, relation=lt - but only one of the rows are needed. Essentially, I only need two relations gt and eq. So, maybe that is better for the ENUM to have values (gt, eq) than (gt, eq, lt)?

Comment: @dnbwise: I think either is fine. One gives you a normalized table. The other is denormalized and requires twice the storage space, but it will make it easier and faster to query. I would say that this is a situation where denormalization is an acceptable trade off.